# Is There A Way To Use Regex Containing Variables To Replace Characters In A String

Tags: java, regex, replace

I already have the code `s.replaceFirst("\\.", "");`. This replaces the dot in the given string s. But my problem is, that it shall be able to change, what is going to be replaced. Like for example, the programm has to replace now a question mark. I tried to do it as following:

```
String characterToReplace = "?";
s = s.replaceFirst("\\" + characterToReplace, "");
```

But that just creates errors.

Comment: What error does it create?

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. What exactly is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [`Pattern.quote`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)), discussed [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-regexp-escape-char):

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

// ...

String characterToReplace = "?";
s = s.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(characterToReplace), "");
```